# ConTeXt: bold titles except for maths with regular weight

Tags: sectioning, context, bold, boldmath

Here is my code :

```
\setuphead[section][style={\ssb\bf}]

\starttext
\section{Hi, my name is Arnaud and I love maths: \math{e^{i\pi} = -1}}
\stoptext
```

I would like it to display `Hi, my name is Arnaud and I love maths:` in bold but the equation in regular weight. Is that possible? By default, both the text and the equation are bold.

I am asking this because I use two fonts (sans & maths) that are not the same weight even though both are set to `bold`. In this case, I prefer to clearly distinguish normal text and equations.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The equation is not bold for me. Is your system up-to-date?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In TL2017 it's bold, in beta it isn't.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It's a bug.  Bold maths does not work at all in beta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, I did not find any high-level switch to turn off automatic font weight deduction for maths.  You just have to operate it out of `\everymathematics`.

```
\unprotect

\removetoks
    \font_helpers_synchronize_math_family % auto bold
\from \everymathematics

\protect

\setuphead[section][style={\ssb\bf}]

\starttext

\startsection[title={Hi, my name is Arnaud and I love maths: \math{e^{i\pi} = -1}}]

  % Manual math bold still works
  Hi, my name is Arnaud and I love maths: \math{\mb e^{i\pi} = -1}

\stopsection

\stoptext
```

[image]

Comment: It's not a high-level switch indeed but it's very efficient! I will therefore accept your answer. Thank you!